# Asynchronous Ajax Script Handling for Web app

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, jakarta-ee

I am trying to develop a complicated app using JavaEE.

So I have currently developed the application to run some scripts on the Backend. Thay have to executed sequentially, Hence I am making requests by using synchronous Ajax calls inside a loop.
But I now need to add a functionality to stop the scripts if they take too long to run.

The problem is I am using synchronous Ajax call. Hence I cant interact with the UI until the response is received.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "Servlet Path",
            data: {
                data: my_data
            },
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                // Display scripts Output
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                console.log("Failure");
            }
        });
```

My plan is to use the process id and run the script "kill -9 pid" to stop the script.

If I use async call then all the scripts will be started at once.

How can I make this happen?